# Pardot prospect link to Salesforce record

Tags: pardot

My question is about updating the mapping between a Pardot prospect and a Salesforce record.

A contact was created first in Salesforce and linked to Pardot's prospect. Later another contact with the same address was created.

What can I do in order to relink existing Pardot record to another existing Saleforce record with the same email address.

The org has "Allow Multiple Prospects with the Same Email Address" disabled.

Answer (score 0):

This is VERY hard to do. Really our only option for manipulating what record Pardot connects to is by manipulating the record visibility to the connector user. This can cause duplication issues where a record is hidden, and Pardot recreates it repeatedly if it's not done correctly.